# Deleting DirectShow Filters (Destructor not called)

Tags: c++, com, directshow, destructor

I have built a custom DirectShow filter that implements CSource such as

```
class Myfilter : public CSource
{
   ~MyFilter(){ delete everything;}
}
```

When I use this filter in GraphStudio, I can delete it properly, the destructor is called correctly.

When I create my filter via COM instaciation, I can no longer delete it with delete

```
IBaseFilter *pFilter = NULL;

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
                              IID_PPV_ARGS(&pFilter));
```

then delete pFilter will not call the destructor.

How can I call my custom destructor for my filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not supposed to `delete` COM objects, you should [`Release()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682317%28VS.85%29.aspx) them.  `CSource` probably implements `IUnknown::Release()` as `delete this`, when the reference count drops to 0.

Comment: Samething with Release() instead of delete

Comment: Then you have a bug somewhere else.  Please post a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I still had references to my filter somewhere. Mostly in my graph building classes that weren't used by GraphStudio

Answer (score 0):

If you've added your filter to a graph, don't forget to remove it from the graph when you're done before releasing your own references.